# Continue query, but show error

Tags: php, mysql, key, unique

Currently I have the following code:

```
$editsystem_exists = "UPDATE `tbl` SET `system_customer`='{$system_customer}', `system_id`='{$system_id}' WHERE `id`='".$systemid_safe."'";
$result_editsystem_exists = mysql_query($editsystem_exists);

if (!$result_editsystem_exists) {
    echo '<font color="#66990F"><B><center>Changes Saved</B><BR>The System ID has not changed.<BR></center></font>';
    echo mysql_error();
} else {
    echo '<font color="#66990F"><B><center>Changes Saved</B><BR></center></font>';
}
```

`system_id` is a unique key. What my problem is, is that I want the query to continue even if the error occurs, but display the error without updating the system_id if it's a duplicate. I have tried using `@` and it doesn't do anything. No matter what I have tried, if it displays the error, the query stops and nothing is updated. I just want it to skip system_id, but update everything else ONLY IF the system_id is a duplicate. If it IS NOT a duplicate, update everything.

**Note: I am developing a module for something that does not support mysqli or PDO. I am stuck using mysql_**

**EDIT: This is my original code**

Before I started playing around with this, this was my original code

```
    #Begin checking for an existing system id
    $system_id_check = "SELECT `system_id` FROM `tbl` WHERE `system_id`='".$system_id."'";
    $search_system_id = mysql_query($system_id_check);
    $result_check = mysql_num_rows($search_system_id);

    if($result_check !== 0){

    #Connect to the DB to get the System ID
    $query_sysid = "SELECT `id`, `system_id` FROM `tbl` WHERE `id`='".$systemid_safe."'";
    $result_sysid = mysql_query($query_sysid); if (!$result_sysid) { die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());}
    $row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result_sysid);

    #Update all but the System ID if it already exists
    $editsystem_exists = "UPDATE `tbl` SET `system_customer`='{$system_customer}' WHERE `id`='".$systemid_safe."'";

    mysql_query($editsystem_exists); echo '<font color="#66990F"><B><center>Changes Saved</B><BR>The System ID has not changed.</center></font>';

} else {  

    #Connect to the DB to get the System ID
    $query_sysid = "SELECT `id`, `system_id` FROM `tbl` WHERE `id`='".$systemid_safe."'";
    $result_sysid = mysql_query($query_sysid); if (!$result_sysid) { die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); }
    $row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result_sysid); 

    #Update the system if the System ID does not exist  
    $editsystem = "UPDATE `tbl` SET `system_customer`='{$system_customer}', `system_id`='{$system_id}' WHERE `id`='".$systemid_safe."'";

    #Success Message
    mysql_query($editsystem); echo '<font color="#66990F"><B><center>Changes Saved</B><BR>The System ID was updated.</center></font>'; }}
```

I just didn't want to display the "Not Changed" or "Changed" messages for any update done. If the System ID already exists, it won't update the System ID field. Instead of seeing "Not Changed" I was wanting to be able to put a reason of why it was not changed, hence the `if` command in the above code. The above example is if the system ID is found.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should check if `system_id` exists using select statement.

```
if (mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE system_id = {$system_id}")) {
    $editsystem_exists = "UPDATE `tbl` SET `system_customer`='{$system_customer}' WHERE `id`='" . $systemid_safe . "'";
} else {
    $editsystem_exists = "UPDATE `tbl` SET `system_customer`='{$system_customer}', `system_id`='{$system_id}' WHERE `id`='" . $systemid_safe . "'";
}
```